# How to change a random date to be the monday of the same week

Tags: php, html, datepicker

Hellow friends,

How do I change a date VARIABLE to represent the monday of the same week?

```
$randomdate = '2018-03-31';
$monday = ??????   // The result should be '2018-03-26'
```

I don't think there is a way to make html5 datepicker to allow users to select only mondays or prevent users from manually type a random date, so I'm planning to do that through PHP.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `new DateTime("2018-03-31 last monday")`: https://3v4l.org/D3G7C. You may need to do something more clever if the date already is a Monday, depending on your requirements.

Comment: or `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2018-03-31 last monday"));`

Comment: So basically I would have to first check if the date is not already a monday, am I right? Any simple line I could use to verify that? Thak you both.

Comment: or try this: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($randomdate) - 24 * 60 * 60 * (date('N', strtotime($randomdate)) - 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
$randomdate = '2018-03-31';
$randomdateTimestamp = strtotime($randomdate);
$mondayTimestamp = $randomdateTimestamp - 24 * 60 * 60 * (date('N', $randomdateTimestamp) - 1);
$monday = date('Y-m-d', $mondayTimestamp);
var_dump($monday);
```

Comment: Thank you lulco, I guess your approach solves the entire thing, even if I give a monday as the random date. thumbs up!

Comment: you're welcome, I wrote shorter version to the comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($randomdate) - 24 * 60 * 60 * (date('N', strtotime($randomdate)) - 1))`

Comment: I just created a function with your code called get_monday($date), so now it's working like a charm.

Comment: use 4+ spaces to indent or highlight code then usr CTRL-K, don't use ticks. I had to edit.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I use syntax from github / gitlab and it works (code was highlighted in some way). I will try to remember to use spaces